# discord.js ( bot ) Error : TypeError: connection.playFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I don't understand why have this error:

> TypeError: connection.playFile is not a function

My code :

```
if (message.member.voice.channel) {

  message.member.voice.channel.join()
  .then(connection => { 
    const dispatcher = connection.playFile(require("path").join(__dirname, './audio.mp3'));

    dispatcher.on('start', () => { //not working
        dispatcher.setVolume(0.70);
        console.log("Playing");
    }); 
    dispatcher.on('error', (err) => console.log(err)); //no errors

        dispatcher.on('end', end => { //working fine
            console.log("Finished");
            console.log("End: " + end);
            message.member.voiceChannel.leave()
        });
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using discord.js v12 , playFile is now play , for more info in [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#voice)
so doing

```js
  message.member.voice.channel.join()
  .then(connection => { 
    const dispatcher = connection.play(require("path").join(__dirname, './audio.mp3'));
```

should fix the issue.

more info
 - https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#the-basics

Comment: Thanks ! But I have a another error after :TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int
opusscript_native_wasm.js:8
Error: "abort(TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info."

Comment: This seems to be a error with the module opusscript itself try using `@discordjs/opus`, you can install it by doing `npm i @discordjs/opus`, or `yarn add @discordjs/opus` if you use yarn.